# How can I get audiobooks from Banshee's 'Internet Archive' plugin into my library?

Tags: banshee

When I view an audiobook in the Internet Archive 'store' in Banshee, there is no option to add it to my library, or even to download the files. I can still stream these files but because I can't view them in my library, I can't get them onto my mp3 player. I am however able to download the files if I do so directly from archive.org.

Is this just a missing feature, or is there actually a reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of how Banshee is setup, it has nothing to do with IA itself.

The main reason you can't download is probably because the Banshee developers didn't care enough to add in that feature, and you can, and probably should, add a request to be able to do that.

You can, however, download the file without opening up your browser. Just open up nautilus or whatever file browser you use and drag the file from the files pane to your nautilus window. You still have to import in Banshee, but at least you don't need to open your web browser.

Comment: The request is already there, but both the IA extension and the Audiobooks extension are fairly new, so they're both still lacking some features.  Feel free to CC yourself to this bug report if you want to stay up-to-date on the progress: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=637125